# Symmetry of hearing and speaking

Tags: acoustics

Can two people be situated such that person A can clearly hear person B, but not vice-versa? Assume that both of them are free to turn any direction in $S^2$ from their position, and that they are allowed to change directions between speaking and hearing.

Even if the answer is theoretically yes, I reckon that one person may need to choose their speaking/hearing angle much more carefully than the other. I'm thinking of a situation where person A is in a cave in a slot canyon and person B is at the top of the canyon. Probably A can talk to B in a wider range of directions than B can talk to A.

Comment: It happens when I listen to the DJ on the radio. No matter how hard I  scream, he just can't hear me asking to play my song. No, seriously. Are there asymmetric walls thinkable that let sound pass in one direction better than in the other? Or maybe big Ear-like shapes, with your ears in the sound focus (like two persons whispering in both foci inside an eipsoid).

Answer (score 2):

Assume Person B is located in an environment with a high level of background noise.

Person A will hear both Person B and B's background noise **attenuated equally** by distance.

Person B will hear Person A attenuated by the same amount due to distance, but will hear **unattenuated background noise** from his own environment.

Values for volume of speech, background noise and distance attenuation can be chosen to achieve the asymmetry you describe...

Comment: Your answer is very nice but as long as the directional distance attenuation from A to B is constant for both noise and voice the only factor that plays a role is the level difference (or ratio) of those two (voice and noise). Additionally, whether the person "in" the noise will here the other person is dependent on the noise of the person outside the noise (for constant directional distance attenuation) versus the background noise. Nevertheless, the phenomenon is a wee bit more involved with (psychoacoustical) masking effect showing in the party. +1 though :).